# Different environment in wsgi request object

Tags: django, python-3.x, uwsgi

After some hours of reading manuals and other helps, finally i got my nginx+uwsgi1.9+django1.6+python3.3 server.

But now I have problems (mb problem in my understanding something) - how to get POST data from request ? I mean how to get it correctly.

The code in django view:

```
def info(request):
    print(request)
    return HttpResponse(request)
```

request to server:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/info/
{   
    "test":"test"
}
```

and interesting part - output in uwsgi log (POST and GET dicts):

```
<WSGIRequest
path:/info/,
GET:<QueryDict: {}>,
POST:<QueryDict: {}>,
COOKIES:{},
META:{'CONTENT_LENGTH': '24',
 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json',
 'CSRF_COOKIE': 'upJxA8TWO0nhKACr0dfU46Qyu0DzzUTR',
 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/usr/share/nginx/html',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT': '*/*',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
 'HTTP_CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH': '24',
 'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json',
 'HTTP_COOKIE': '',
 'HTTP_HOST': '127.0.0.1:8000',
 'HTTP_ORIGIN': 'chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo',
 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36',
 'PATH_INFO': '/info/',
 'QUERY_STRING': '',
 'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
 'REMOTE_PORT': '53315',
 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'POST',
 'REQUEST_URI': '/info/',
 'SCRIPT_NAME': '',
 'SERVER_NAME': 'django',
 'SERVER_PORT': '8000',
 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',
 'uwsgi.node': b'',
 'uwsgi.version': b'1.9.18.2',
 'wsgi.errors': <_io.TextIOWrapper name=2 mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>,
 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in function uwsgi_sendfile>,
 'wsgi.input': <uwsgi._Input object at 0x7fa4ec6b8ee8>,
 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,
 'wsgi.multithread': False,
 'wsgi.run_once': False,
 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',
 'wsgi.version': (1, 0)}>
```

and response in browser (same as request to server):

```
{   
    "test":"test"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

```
request.POST
and 
request.POSt.dict()
```

returns empty dicts.

So questions is how to get POST data in code and why it looks so different when I use environment ?

**UPD**:
return HttpResponse(str(request)) - returns WSGIRequest object instead of POST data to me. But still dont know how to get POST data in code.

**UPD2**: 
uwsgi config:

```
[uwsgi]
module = mysite.wsgi
master          = true
processes       = 5
socket = :8001
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/mysite.log
touch-reload = /tmp/uwsgi-touch
post-buffering = 1
```

**UPD3**:
versions of software:

```
Python 3.3.2
Django 1.6.2
uWSGI 1.9.18.2
```

**UPD4:**

Final code:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.META["CONTENT_TYPE"] == "application/json":
        result = json.loads(request.body.decode())
    else: result = request.POST.dict()
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
```

Thats what I exactly want.
When I send data to server with

```
POST 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
a=1
```

or:

```
POST 
Content-Type: application/json
{"a":"1"}
```

I see same response (and in code variables):

```
Content-Type: application/json
{"a": "1"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you a POSTing JSON data, not HTML form data.

In that case you are looking for the raw post data, which is accessed like this:

```
request.body
```

See [`HttpRequest.body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) in the documentation.

If you want to parse that JSON string, use this:

```
import json
data = json.loads(request.body)
```

The `request.POST` dictionary is only populated when the request contains form data. This is when the `Content-Type` header is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Yep, its json. I thought its just string or QueryDict object. But why there difference in result of print() and HttpResponse() ? Why it is not same WSGIRequest or POST objects ? –  Alex T 31 mins ago

Comment: ehh... I mean why I see different result between HttpResponse(request) and print(request) ?

Comment: `return HttpResponse(request)` should return an empty response, because request is not a string.  `print(request)` will print a representation of the request, because it automatically calls `str(request)` before outputting

Comment: but `return HttpResponse(request)` returns content of POST, I mean content of `request.POST` which I want to get in my code :>

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: `>>> django.get_version()  
'1.6.2'`

Comment: `HttpRequest` is an iterator, that returns the lines of text from the `body` attribute.  If the object passed to `HttpResponse` is an iterator, it uses the contents of that iterator.  So `return HttpResponse(request)` calls `iter(request)`, and hence the response is the contents of `request.body`.  When you `print(response)`, it's doing `print(str(response))` which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: Anyway, I take it that using my answer, you've gotten the result you wanted?

Comment: Almost, but thanks your answer explained much more than docs. In additional to your answer - `request.body` is byte objest, so it should be decoded. I'll update my post a bit later.